# MNE: set EEG reference to 1/2 of a channel

Tags: python, data-preprocessing, mne-python

I am trying to rereference my EEG data to 0.5 of the mastoid (TP9). I tried different lines of code, but cannot seem to find a solution.

I cannot multiply the ref_channels in the set_eeg_reference function. Now, I attempted to create a new channel with the function mne.channels.combine_channels but this also does not work. Does anyone know a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, As previously commented, you need to elaborate a bit more. Butfrom what i understood, rereferencing data to average works fine, but obviously after excluding any bad channels.
You can use this line of code

```
raw1 = raw.copy().set_eeg_reference(ref_channels="average")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar case where my signal was recorded using a left earlobe reference (A1) and I wanted to re-reference data to the average of both earlobes (A1 and A2). You can do this easily using MNE:

```
raw.add_reference_channels('A1')
raw.set_eeg_reference(ref_channels=['A1', 'A2'])
```

The first line, add a new dummy channel named A1 and set it to zero. The second line set EEG reference to average of A1 and A2 which is equal to half of A2 (because A1 is zero).